# Can I include static resources in my Liferay Portlet?

Tags: liferay, portlet

We have a Liferay portlet application with many different portlets deployed.

If have a single portlet that needs a static .js file served how can I add this to only the portlet in question?

Previously we had added .css/ and .js files included by portlets to the theme. In this case only one portlet needs this file.  Is it possible to include this file and serve it statically within a .war deployed for a single portlet?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare required JS or CSS files in liferay-portlet.xml. This file has options for adding them to the header or footer of the page. Look up the very [well documented DTD](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd.html#header-portal-css) of that file to figure out the options and positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do as you suggested in put the js file in a 'static resources portlet' to be consumed by all of your other portlets like a simple CDN.

Remember that to access the js file you will need to hit the portlet context so: localhost:8080/static-resources-portlet/js/awesome.js